# docker-compose running any command gives error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, containers

I searched the internet no good answer was found anywhere. When I run docker-compose up, down, or any command I am having this error.

```
cannot update snap namespace: cannot create symlink in "/etc/docker": existing file in the way    
snap-update-ns failed with code 1
```

It was working fine, suddenly having this issue.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 docker version 20.10.8

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [69134662](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69134662/4346453), see [69163328](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69163328/4346453)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not install the docker, you may run:

```
sudo snap install docker          # version 20.10.8, or
```

Otherwise:

```
sudo apt  install docker-compose  # version 1.25.0-1
```

Hoping that this will help you!